# Wrong reputation scale on FAQ

Tags: bug, status-norepro, faq-suggestion

On the FAQ page the reputation scale from the Public BETA is still present where it should reflect the current scale.

Comment: I think it should be fixed fast...

Comment: who has access to edit the FAQ? only the devs?

Comment: Moderators have very limited access to the FAQs. It would need to be done by an admin on the SO team

Comment: ****grumbles**** Lost my access to the moderation tools. Oh well. Only ~4600 points to go to get them back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reputation levels are correct in the system. Your browser is likely still caching the previous version of that page. Clear your browser's cache (Ctrl-F5, on many systems) to get the most recent page.